# How come when I move a python file into scipy.stats folder in ubuntu it disappears?

Tags: python

I downloaded http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/attachment/ticket/846/mvncdf.py

I: sudo mv ~/Downloads/mvncdf.py /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/scipy/stats

and it disappears

I also tried saving directly to /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/scipy/stats and it still disappears.

Overall I'm not sure how to move this so that I can call it from a python program if I have imported scipy.stats, scipy.stats.kde, etc. This is what I'm really trying to solve.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It disappears immediately or after you run something else?

Comment: @FatalError No I do this and it is not in scipy.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm trying to find the cdf of a multivariate (2) normal distribution

Comment: I think the issue is that you're copying it into the wrong directory. The files in that directory appear to be only sym links to the ones in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats. That said, I wouldn't really recommend adding to the package this way. If you distribute your script, nobody else will be able to run it without doing a similar mod to their scipy. What's wrong with just leaving it in the same directory as your code and importing it from there?

Comment: @FatalError2 thanks, I'm trying this.

Comment: just FYI: It's also in the statsmodels sandbox without many changes http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras.mvstdnormcdf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to import external libraries in python.  The simplest is to launch the program or interpreter from the same directory as the file, so

```
$ mkdir new_program
$ mv ~/Downloads/mvncdf.py new_program/.
$ cd new_program
$ python
>>> import mvncdf
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @tcaswell, you can add a local path to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable,

```
$ mkdir ~/python_scripts 
$ mv ~/Downloads/mvncdf.py python_scripts/.
$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/python_scripts
$ export PYTHONPATH
```

The last two lines can be placed in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` so that the variable is set every time you log in.

A more permanent way is to find a directory in your `sys.path`  where such local user "installed" programs should go.  By convention, this is in one of the `site-packages` directories for your distribution.  If your using python version 2.7, this would probably be:

```
$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/mvncdf.py /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/.
```

You can check which directories are in your `sys.path` from the python shell

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
...     print i
...
```

However, placing your own files in something like `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` is discouraged as they may get over-written during a python update.  The most proper way, and the way that adheres closest to the FHS, is to create a `site-packages` directory under `/usr/local`, e.g.,

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Then edit `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py`, find the `PREFIXES` variable, and add the new directory to the list, e.g.,

```
PREFIXES = [sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix, '/usr/local']
```

Ubuntu may already have this directory in `sys.path`, so check before creating it and editing `site.py`.  Of course, if you do have to modify `site.py`, then you run in to the same issues when upgrading python that you would by just placing a file in a directory under `/usr/lib`.

Comment: can also add directories to `$PYTHONPATH` which are added to sys.path

Comment: You have to re-source the file and re-launch python after you add it.  I use this everyday on ubuntu, debian, and arch.  in my `.bashrc`: `PYTHONPATH=/home/tcaswell/local_installs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH` followed by `export PYTHONPATH`

Comment: ah, ok, `export PYTHONPATH` was the key that I've been missing.  Thanks.  With that this works in Fedora as well.